# using jquery validationengine in jquery ui tabs - more form

Tags: jquery, jquery-tabs, jquery-validation-engine

i've jquery ui tabs.each tabs contain different form

i use this code to validate the form

```
function bindAjaxValidation(idForm){
    jQuery("#"+idForm).validationEngine('detach');
    jQuery("#"+idForm).validationEngine('hideAll');
    jQuery("#"+idForm).validationEngine({
        validateNonVisibleFields: true,
        updatePromptsPosition:true,
        ajaxFormValidation: true,
        ajaxFormValidationMethod: 'post',
        onAjaxFormComplete: ajaxValidationCallback,
        promptPosition : "topLeft:0"

    });
}
```

all works fine on first tabs. when i switch to onother tabs validation start but errors are not shown.

this solution non help me

[jQuery-Validation-Engine wrong position popup on field hidden (jquery tabs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862786/jquery-validation-engine-wrong-position-popup-on-field-hidden-jquery-tabs)

Comment: why negative vote? it would be more useful a comment that explains why

Answer (score 0):

the solution is simple. id must have unique id.

from offical documentation

http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoMultipleForms.html